# fetch all rows from mysql db with php using aFetch($sql) problem

Tags: php, mysql

i inherited this code from some-one and this only returns the first row it finds:

```
function getMessages($userID, $from, $limit)
{
  $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM rc_message_box_table WHERE profile_id_to = {$userID} AND rc_message_box_table.profile_id_from NOT IN (SELECT profile_id_block FROM rc_blocklist_table WHERE profile_id = {$id}) LIMIT {$from}, {$limit}";
  $row = $this->aFetch($sql);
  return $row;
}

function aFetch($sSql)
{   
//print_r($sSql);
$aResults = array();
if(is_string($sSql))
{
      $fnSql = $this->query($sSql);
    }

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fnSql))
   {
  $aResults[] = $row;
   }
   return  $aResults;       
}
```

how can i with this code return all rows where profile_id_to = {$userID} ??
thanks

Comment: Code looks like it should return multiple rows as-is.  Are you certain the query returns more than one if you run it manually with the same parameters?

Comment: please post a var_dump($aResults);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function aFetch($result = false) {
        if($result)
            return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        else
            return mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result);
    }
```

you can use this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your result may be limited by `$from`, `$limit` parameters.

Look at the code where `getMessages` is being invoked, and analyse what values it is passing.

Comment: the  $from, $limit parameters is for limiting the amount of messages per page :) this code is for a mobi site...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM rc_message_box_table
WHERE profile_id_to = {$userID}
AND rc_message_box_table.profile_id_from NOT IN
(
    SELECT profile_id_block
    FROM rc_blocklist_table
    WHERE profile_id = {$id}
)
```